# MySQL error 1005  when creating a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

When running the following statement:

```
CREATE  TABLE `intelischool`.`facultyclasses` (
  `id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `class` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `subject` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `year` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `section` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `section`, `year`, `subject`, `class`) ,
  INDEX `id` (`id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id` )
    REFERENCES `intelischool`.`faculty` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'intelischool.facultyclasses' (errno: 121)
```

Comment: all fields of table as PRIMARY KEY is BAD DESIGN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This mailing list thread](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/164229) is about the same problem, and the conclusion reached there was that it was caused by a duplicate constraint name.

You probably have another

```
CONSTRAINT `id`
```

in another table of the same databse. Those names need to be unique per database. Give it a name like

```
CONSTRAINT `facultyclasses_foreignkey`
```

or just delete that line and let the database generate a name for it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Missing comma before Foreign key defination

otherwise

Dropped the tables and created them with an index (instead of adding an index to an already created tables)